# How to include with rails-assets.org a package with a . in the name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, bower

I'm using rails 4.1 with https://rails-assets.org .

I want to include this bower package in my Rails project:

https://github.com/wysiwygjs/wysiwyg.js

They say to include it like that:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-BOWER_PACKAGE_NAME'
end
```

So I tried:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
    gem "rails-assets-wysiwyg.js"
end
```

And:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
   gem "rails-assets-wysiwygjs"
end
```

And also:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
    gem "rails-assets-wysiwyg_js"
end
```

None worked. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it's something with that package/gem itself?  I just tried with watch.js which is already built (maybe wysiwyg isn't and the problem lies there?) and it worked just fine:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-watch.js'
end
```

Output of `bundle install`:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Installing rails-assets-watch.js 0.1.0
Using bundler 1.7.11
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: You're right. It seems that the problem is that wysiwyg.js is not correctly bower-ed.